# revert back to unhovered css on key down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onkeydown

I have an element when you hover over it changes the css I have added a onkeydown function that reverts back to the original css. I was just wondering if there was anyway of getting the unhovered css with out writing it all out again?

here is my code

```
            $(document).keydown(function(e) {

            if (e.keyCode == 27) {
                $(NBSmegamenu).css('display', 'none');}   // esc
                $(".dynamic-children").css('border-bottom-width','none');
                $(".dynamic-children").css('border-bottom-style','none');
                $(".dynamic-children").css('border-bottom-color','none');

                $(".HoverImg").remove();
                $("span.dynamic-children").css('background-position', 'right'); 
                $("span.dynamic-children").css('background-image', 'url("/Style%20Library/NBSImages/NBS_MegaMenuDownArrowRed.png")');
                $("span.dynamic-children").css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
                $(".NBSDirectoryDivLine").css('border','none');

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better use classes:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
     if (e.keyCode == 27) 
       $(element).addClass(keyDownCssClass);
});
```

and you just have to remove it on key up:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
     if (e.keyCode == 27) 
       $(element).removeClass(keyDownCssClass);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the css as two classes.  Overwrite which ever properties you need in the hover class.  Ensure that hover class is defined after the unhovered class, so that it takes precedence.

In your javascript simply toggle the classes on/off.

$(document).keydown(function(e) {

```
        if (e.keyCode == 32) { // Space to hover
           $(NBSmegamenu).addClass('hover');
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 27) // Unhover
           $(NBSmegamenu).removeClass('hover');
        }
```